# How many times I should use the session for each user

Tags: php, session

We are using session in `login.php` and the user enters into site.

If the user sends new requests to another `php` files, should we use in that `php` files the session commands again??

If I use session operations only in `login.php` file, is enough?

Comment: No. If a user is assigned session information you must maintain the session on each page the user may visit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `$_SESSION['Variable']` to be available in any other page you must start the page with `<?php session_start(); ?>`

Remember to have a `$_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = TRUE;` or something similiar to set an OK authentication by checking this on every logged in are only page:

```
<?php 
session_start(); 

if($_SESSION['LoggedIn'] == FALSE){ 
//NOT LOGGED IN! 
} 

else{ 
//THE USER IS LOGGED IN! :) 
}
```